# Regex only allow alphanumeric

Tags: regex

I am trying to do the following with regex...

- Only A-Z and 0-9
- Not one character in its own
- Can not be just numbers on their own
- Can be just letters on their own but at least 2 characters

I have this so far [http://regex101.com/r/yW1pV8](http://regex101.com/r/zD1jP8) ...

```
.*[a-zA-Z]{2,}+.*
```

This seems to meet my critera except that it doesn't stop me from putting in other charactes such as $ _ ! etc...

Some correct test data is...

```
579 International Road
International Road
```

Some incorrect data is...

```
679
3
$£
A
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your example has no test data.......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.*` matches *anything*, which isn't what you want it seems. Also, you don't need the `+`, since `X{n,}` already means `X` *at least* `n` times. Lastly, you forgot the `0-9` part. So it looks like this will do:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}
```

Some regex flavors have `[a-zA-Z0-9]` as a pre-defined character class. For example, in Java it's `\p{Alnum}`.

If you also want to allow for spaces (as per your test data), use `\s`:

```
(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me with my test data, I have updated the original post with this data

Comment: @fightstarr20 Looks like you also want to allow for spaces. See the edit.

Comment: Yeah just spotted that, was missing the space!  This now works better but does still allow numbers to be on their own

Comment: Plus, now the space counts as a character

Comment: @fightstarr20 Ok, I'm starting to understand the requirements. Try the edit.

Comment: Starting to get there!  It still allows all numbers though

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{2,}$/);
alert(pattern.test(value) + value);
```

For alpha number